# Figuring out Laravel 5 app namespace from a package

Tags: php, laravel, namespaces, package, laravel-5

I'm developing a package for Laravel 5 and need to know the application namespace, how can I get it?

I saw there is `Illuminate\Console\AppNamespaceDetectorTrait` but it needs some Foundation helpers as well as an instance of the application container to make them work and it's tricky to **test** during the development of a package.

**Edit**: for the time being I'm wrapping that trait into an interface to create isolation, but wondering if there is a better solution.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know what's supposed to not work with the `AppNamespaceDetectorTrait`. Just use it and call `getAppNamespace()`:

```
class Foo {
    use Illuminate\Console\AppNamespaceDetectorTrait;

    public function bar(){
        echo $this->getAppNamespace();
    }
}
```

Comment: Yeah, the problem is that `AppNamespaceDetectorTrait` tight couples my package with the user application and I can't unit test. For the time being I'm wrapping that trait into an interface to create isolation, but wondering if there is a better solution.

Comment: Ah now I see the problem. Well alternatively you could just copy the code from the trait in a class of yours and remove the Laravel dependencies. It's just a function that parses `composer.json` after all.

Answer (score 0):

Try copying in getAppNamespace() function into a generic helpers file that can be accessed anywhere in your app. Then, you don't need to tie the AppNamespaceDetectorTrait trait to your class.

**helpers.php**

```
function getAppNamespace()
{
    $composer = json_decode(file_get_contents(base_path().'/composer.json'), true);
    foreach ((array) data_get($composer, 'autoload.psr-4') as $namespace => $path)
    {
        foreach ((array) $path as $pathChoice)
        {
            if (realpath(app_path()) == realpath(base_path().'/'.$pathChoice)) return $namespace;
        }
    }
    throw new RuntimeException("Unable to detect application namespace.");
}
```

And then in **YourClass.php**

```
$namespace = getAppNamespace();  // App\
```